# Ubuntu 20.04 with "cinnamon-desktop-environment". The drop-down menu opens on click but closes when I release the button

Tags: 20.04, menu, cinnamon

I have installed "cinnamon-desktop-environment" on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit.
I am attaching a video in which I open any dropdown menu. Any dropdown menu of any application suffers the same problem:

https://youtu.be/f07s2vs3r2I

I also tried on Linux Mint 20.1, same problem. If the click is very short, the drop-down menu remains open, if I hold down slightly more and then release, the drop-down menu closes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have not encountered this bug in Linux Mint Cinnamon. Check if updating cinnamon to the latest version works https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263649/how-can-i-install-latest-version-of-cinnamon-in-ubuntu/1335805#1335805 (Note: Updating may also break the installation, and you would have to reinstall, so use at your own risk - take a backup of your important files first).

Comment: I also tried on Linux Mint 20.1, same problem. If the click is very short, the drop-down menu remains open, if I hold down slightly more and then release, the drop-down menu closes.

Comment: If you really want to use Cinnamon, and ready to switch operating system, then use Mint instead. This issue is not present there. Note that Mint is not on topic on this website.

Comment: I also tried on Linux Mint 20.1, same problem.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1954

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/258

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using a Mac? From that gitlab link it seemed that only Macs are affected.

Comment: No, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have this same issue on my desktop PC dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem and was able to solve it with the following steps:

1. Right mouse click on the panel
2. Select Applets
3. Select Main Cinnamon Menu
4. Select Configure icon
5. Enable the "Open the menu when I move my mouse over it" toggle button

The menu now opens when the mouse hovers over it. I prefer to click to open but there doesn't seem to be a setting for that.